# How to implement mqtt over websockets in browser clients?

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, web-notifications, shared-worker

I'm trying to use mqtt over websocket in my web application using the [Paho JS library](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/js/index.php) to implement notifications. I need to use persistent connection(to receive any pending messages) and for that a unique client id is a must.

Problem 1: **Multiple tabs acting as a mqtt client using the same client id and hence disconnecting and connecting in infinite loop(as I've set reconnect to true)**

I solved the above problem using Shared Worker which is now using only one connection for all the tabs which is great. But now I've run into another problem.

Problem 2: **When I open my application in two different browsers say, Chrome and Firefox, I get different shared workers and hence again two clients using the same clientId resulting in connect/disconnect loop.**

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Simplest solution: don't open the application in two different browsers - why would you need to?

Comment: @JaromandaX You can't restrict a user from opening the application in multiple browsers. It's one of the test cases.

Comment: you need to consider how is it that two different browsers end up with the same clientId ... where does the clientId come from? do it differently

Comment: I've set the clientId manually for my web application. I've not set it based on the type of browser. I could just append random numbers to my clientId every time I make a connection. But then I won't be able to make a persistent connection. And as a result will lose messages stored on the broker against that clientId

Comment: well, you'll need to figure something out then ... perhaps use `navigator.userAgentData?.brands[2].brand || 'Firefox'` ... which will give you a distinct string in Chrome, Edge (Chrome based) and Firefox

Comment: note: currently firefox does not implement `navigator.userAgentData` - I only know that chromium based browsers do ... so, the above may not be the best solution, but it will distinguish between chrome and firefox, the two browsers you mention

Comment: Not sure if this will solve anything, but check out "cotonic" (.org & github). It is the backbone of Zotonic and is essentially a MQTT broker in the browser with web workers connecting to that topic tree.